# How can i make a network request when the user opens an activity but only if 24 hours have passed since the last request?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that sends a network request to get some data from an API and saves it in a database, but its sending the request every time the user opens the activity, Is there a way to make the request only if 24 hours have passed since the last request ?

Comment: save time to preference when you called api in activity. next time check previous time with current time. If current time greate than 24 from prev api call time,call your api

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can store your last hit time in shared preference and when the user opens that activity gets the last saved time and compare with current time if it is greater the 24 hours then hit your API otherwise don't do any action. To create a shared reference class like this:-

```
public class AppPrefrences {

            private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
            private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

    public static String getLastTime(Context ctx) {
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            return mPrefs.getString("lstTime", "");
        }

        public static void setLastTime(Context ctx, String value) {
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            mPrefsEditor.putString("lastTime", value);
            mPrefsEditor.commit();
        }

public static void clearAllData(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.clear();
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
        }
```

to set your time do this:-

```
setLastTime(this, "current time");
```

to get last time:-

```
String lastTime = getLastTime(this);
```

now in lastTime you got your last time api hit time now get current time and compare both time and do your code.

Comment: No need to have a static SharedPreference which you constantly re-initialize. Also, we don't have to use `.commit`, use `.apply()` instead if you care about performance and not freezing the UI thread.This code is quite inefficient. Also, why is last time of type `String` instead of `Long` or `Int`?

Comment: `commit` is slower. That's a fact. Check the `SharedPreference.Editor` documentation: "Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures" https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: Constantly re-initialize is a waste of memory and can unnecessarily trigger the garbage collector which will drop frames https://www.careerride.com/Java-disadvantage-of-garbage-collector.aspx. That's a fact. If you think these facts are wrong then please educate me